# Django - Admin Area width

Tags: css, django, django-admin, margin

My admin area on my Django application is a little bit off since a few days. I don't know what I did wrong...

At the moment, the width is not fully used by the tables and the forms. The buttons instead are using the full width.

Where can I change the width to full for the forms and tables? Is this a problem in Django or just visualization? In the second screenshot you can see, that the area should be on the full width.

PS: It's not a browser problem, I tried.

Cheers guys :)

[Screenshot Django Admin Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9eO8.png)

[Screenshot Django Admin Area with selected width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuTMr.png)

Comment: have you collected static files? if you are extending the admin., are the stylesheets getting loaded?

Comment: Yes, the styles you see in the screenshots is from my static css. It worked fine until one day all the data was on the left on the screen and not extended on full width. I haven't changed anything related to width in my custom css. Can it be a problem of Django itself or does it have to be a problem of css?